# MSAccess: SELECT INTO NewTable cuts long texts

Tags: ms-access

When I use (in MS Access 2003 SP3):

```
SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM SomeQuery;
```

MEMO fields are converted to TEXT fields (which are limited to 255 characters), so longer texts are cut.

The output of the query itself is fine and not truncated; the text is cut only in the new table that is created.

An update: I managed to focus the problem on the IIF statement in my query.
When I remove the IIF, the new table contains the MEMO field, but with the IIF the same field appears as TEXT. The weird thing is that the query output shows the long strings in full, even when the IIF is being used. Only when it is 'copied' to the new table (by the INTO statement), the text is cut.

Do you know of any problems that IIF may cause to MEMO fields?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: As mentioned in VonC's excellently detailed post, memo fields are truncated to max 255 characters when used in a query with a function.

Answer (score 3):

You have here the [current workarounds](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html) for avoiding any Truncation of Memo fields.

In your case, that may be the result of the query's Properties Sheet including a "`set Unique`" Values to Yes (which forces comparison of Memo fields, triggering the truncation), or the Format property of the field, e.g. forcing display in upper case (`>`) or lower case (`<`).

---

What Access are you using, and what format are you saving your document into ?

In a Access 2000 compatible format, the cell are in [Excel5.0/95 format](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208801): 255 characters max.

Do you have any other (non-Memo) field with lengthy value you could try to select, just to see if it also gets truncated ?

---

If the output is fine, but the export in a new table does truncate the Memo fields, could you check the following:

[In the export dialog under advanced](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/archive/index.php/t-108089.html), even though it looks like you can only inlude the name, if you click very carefully to expand column that don't appear, you can change the data type to memo.

Comment: Just found the same page. This problem is not mentioned there. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak: the problem may not be directly linked to the SQL query, but to other parameters like the field format. I have completed my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, VonC.
Unfortunately, that didn't work. I don't have the Unique flag set, nor do I have any formatting done on the string.
I also read the current workarounds, but none of them seems to apply to my case.
I'm puzzeld...

Comment: Could you try to select only the memo field, not '*' ? Just to check if in that case (Memo field selected alone), there still is a truncation ?

Comment: If this is not related to the format of the field, there should be some comparison of Memo field involved in the execution of this request.

Comment: I wish there was, cause I would have been able to remove it.
I export the entire output of the query, so there is nothing to compare.
The query I posted in my question is the same as in my database, only the table & query names are different. It is a very basic query that simply doesn't work for me

Comment: Just added another suggestion

Comment: by the way, the output of the query itself is fine, nothing is cut.
Only when I insert the output into a new table the text is truncated.

Comment: May be this is an interesting detail to add to your question (that you can edit)

Comment: And... added another suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested in A2K3 with a make table and appending a memo field. I had no difficulty getting it to append full data to a memo field.

Perhaps you could post the SQL for the query you're using to populate your table. If you're sorting (or grouping) on the memo fields that could do it, because sorting on memo fields is supposed to truncate them to 255 characters (though in the test I just ran on A2K3 SP3 with all the latest post-SP3 patches, mere sorting doesn't truncate but GROUP BY does).

Another issue is that it's usually not advisable to have a Make Table query in a production app. Anything that's happening repeatedly enough that you programmed for it really ought to be appending to a pre-defined table, instead of replacing an existing table. For one, a pre-defined table can have indexes defined on it, which makes it much more efficient to use after it's been populated. Sure, you have to delete existing records before appending your new data, but the benefit is pretty big in terms of indexing. And, yes, you could redefine indexes each time you run your Make Table query, but, well, if it's too much trouble to delete existing data, isn't it even *more* work to add indexes to the newly-created table?

I hardly ever use Make Table queries except when I'm manipulating data that I'm massaging for some other purpose. It's not always predictable what data types you'll end up with in a target table because it is partly dependent on the data in your source table. That alone makes it inadvisable to use them in most situations.

Comment: Causes of MEMO truncation: GROUP BY; UNION ALL. 

No trunction for MEMO data: DISTINCTROW; ORDER BY; set functions FIRST and LAST; UNION. 

Cannot apply to MEMO data: DISTINCT; set functions other then FIRST and LAST (MAX, MIN, AVG, etc).

Answer (score 0):

SP3 of 2003 is notorious, it may be related to that. There is a hotfix:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/945674

Comment: I installed the hotfix, but the behavior is the same. All MEMO fields show up as TEXT fields in the new table.